# Getting a file from a form in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 using Zend. Everything is working except I can't get access to the file in the POST[] array.

Is there anyway I can easily take the file from the form. All the documentation examples only show you how to do this when uploading a file to your local file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uploading a file to your PHP script from a form, and then intend to upload that file to S3, you're looking in the wrong superglobal.

File uploads live in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.  Check out [the PHP documentation on handling file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for information on how to use it best.

Comment: Is there a Zend standard way to handle $_FILE from within my controller?

Comment: I expected to find it in the Request bits, but it turns out that there's a class called [Zend_File_Transfer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html) designed to handle uploads via POST.  What bizarre naming.

Comment: How do I get access to the part of the array that holds the actual. It looks like I HAVE to set a 'setDestination' which is obviously now what I want to do as I want to upload it to s3. I've got the code to upload to s3. I just to pass the file/image to this code.

Comment: No idea, I don't use that part of ZF, and just use `$_FILES` directly, where `$_FILES['form_element_name']['tmp_name']` is the name of the temporary file in which PHP has put the uploaded data.  That's the file you'd want to send to S3.

Comment: All that is doing is uploading the temp_name of the image in a text document. ['form_element_name']['tmp_name'] is just a string?

Comment: `form_element_name` is the name of the `<input type="file" ... >` that uploaded the file.  [`tmp_name` is documented here](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), with all the other keys in the `$_FILES` array.  I heartily encourage you to read the documentation for more information about how file uploads work (and not just 'cause I'm about to go to bed and thus won't be able to answer further questions until the morning :) )...

Comment: Great Help. All sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite straight forward once you get the hang of it.

```
$form->image->setDestination('path/to/images');

if($form->isValid($_POST)){

  if($form->image->isUploaded()){

     if($form->image->receive()){
       // For example, get the filename of the upload
       $filename = $form->image->getFilename();
     }

  } else {
     // Not uploaded
  }

} else {
  // Not valid
}
```

Note that in my example *image* is the name of the upload element.

Answer (score 2):

A small correction on the above it should be `getFileName` with a capital N.

`$filename = $form->image->getFileName();`